# Write a single JSON from multiple dictionaries

Tags: python, json

I am trying to write multiple may be 20 dictionaries into a single json file by appending/dumping one by one onto a JSON file, So far I've done the below code to accomplish but i can't. help if someone know better approach

```
run1 = client.send_get('get_tests/11023')
run2 = client.send_get('get_tests/11038')

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(run1, fp)
```

Comment: Try json.dumps(run1, fp)

Comment: dumps is for converting to string.

Comment: You must to convert list/dict to string by json.dumps(), then insert to file.

Comment: How do you plan to merge the JSON files? Do you want each result as an entry in a top-level array, a dict, or do you want to merge entries?

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure this is possible. What do you expect when you read the contents of the file back?

When you read something out of a file, it should be valid json for it to load. One option is to create a dictionary like so

```
d = dict(run1 = run1, run2 = run2, ... )
```

and then `json.dump`  `d` itself into the file.

*Update:*
Here is an example. This uses a list instead of a dictionary (based on your comment) but the idea is the same.

```
run1 = dict(status = "ok", message = "All good")
run2 = dict(status = "error", message = "Couldn't connect")

def save_data(*runs):
   with open("foo.json", "w") as f:
      json.dump(list(runs), f)

def load_data(fname):
   with open(fname) as f:
      return json.load(f)


save_data(run1, run2)
outputs = load_data("foo.json")
print (outputs)

[{'status': 'ok', 'message': 'All good'}, {'status': 'error', 'message': "Couldn't connect"}]
```

Comment: this will work but i dont want each dictionary to start with run1, run2, run3 etc

Comment: You can, then, create a list like so `[run1, run2, ...]` and dump that as a whole. My point is that the thing you dump into a file should be a single object. I'd recommend the dictionary though and then read out the keys separately as part of your load function.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
run1 = client.send_get('get_tests/11023')
run2 = client.send_get('get_tests/11038')

with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dumps({'run1': run1, 'run2': run2}, fp)
```

If you want to push just single dict in file, you have to merge run1 and run2:

```
run1.update(run2)
```

Then try:

```
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dumps(run1, fp)
```

Also you can try this:

```
with open('result.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dumps({**run1, **run2}, fp)
```

Comment: this will work but i dont want each dictionary in the json to start with run1, run2, run3 etc, because I dont know how many dictionaries gonna be. so!